# Sum bytes from iptables list output

Tags: linux

Print num-bytes allowed.

My best attempt as been

```
sudo iptables -L -n -v -x | grep -i accept
```

This will give me a large list of rules, including the number of bytes in the second column. Unfortunately, getting just that 2nd column is pretty difficult.

One option would be to pipe it into a file, and use cut on the file but the goal is to do it in as few operations as possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include a MCVE.

Comment: You can't use `awk`, but can you use any other non Unix Core tool like `perl`?

Comment: Yeah, our goal is just to minimize process calls.

Comment: @BashOverride: if the table is big, you might get better results from using `awk`.  bash `read` loops are not fast, since they have to `read(2)` one byte at a time to avoid overshooting a newline.  You can do the filtering in awk, and just have `iptables | awk ...`.  If the table is small, then John1024's pure-bash answer could do the filtering on `accept` for you as well.  `[[ $rest == ACCEPT* ]] && ((c+=nbyte))`.  Matching ACCEPT only at the beginning of the 3rd field avoids matching `policy ACCEPT`, in case any chains have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bash command adds up the second column:

```
c=0; while read a nbyte rest; do ((c+=nbyte)); done < <(sudo iptables -L -n -v -x | grep -i accept); echo $c
```

Or, written over multiple lines:

```
c=0
while read a nbyte rest
do
    ((c+=nbyte))
done < <(sudo iptables -L -n -v -x | grep -i accept)
echo $c
```

#### How it works

- `c=0`

  This initializes the count to zero.
- `while read a nbyte rest; do`

  This reads a line of input and assigns the first column to `a`, the second to `nbyte`, and all remaining columns to `rest`.
- `((c+=nbyte))`

  This adds the value in `nbyte` to `c`.  If `nbyte` contains a string, not a number, bash helpfully treats the string as if it were zero.
- `done < <(sudo iptables -L -n -v -x | grep -i accept)`

  This completes the `while` loop and also supplies input to it via *process substitution*.
- `echo $c`

  This displays the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already fine with a pipe through `grep`, then we can replace `grep` with `awk` at no extra cost, and handle all your math inside `awk`.

If you would include a sample of the output from your iptables command, that would be handy.  Though even without it, I expect you might be able to use this:

```
sudo iptables -L -n -v -x | awk 'tolower($0)~/accept/{n+=$2} END{printf("%d\n",n)}'
```

The first condition looks for a case insensitive "accept" in the line, and if it finds it, adds the second whitespace-delimited field to a variable.

The second condition runs when the input is complete, and simply prints the variable.